# Wordpress - uploading images to featured image isn't working

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am attempting to create my first custom Wordpress theme. Everything is going pretty good up until this point. When creating posts, the "Add featured image" option was missing. I went to screen options and it wasn't there. I did some research and found out I needed to add this to my functions.php file:

```
<?php add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); ?>
```

The featured image box was then showing up. However when I try to upload images, I get "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

Answer (score 0):

Have you deactivated all your plugins and tried? If you don't have any plugins set, I'm wondering if it could be a permissions issue, either in the uploads/ directory or an internal permissions error (example: you're not logged in as the admin, but in a different account with fewer privleges.)

Answer (score 0):

usual problems in my experience:

- (like stated above) - check if /wp-content/uploads is writable (group or all, depends on hoster)
- try a small ( < 1000x1000) image first. If that works, but still fails for bigger ones, then your webspace doesn't have enough RAM to calculate the thumbnail. Resize your images before uploading then.